# Download to USB stick

Tags: usb, downloads

I downloaded 12.10 and I'm trying to put it on a USB stick, but when I got it downloaded, it opened a disc burner. I don't have any blank discs and the download is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a bootable USB drive using `usb-creator-gtk`. Or for Windows you could use [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download), which is an easy-to-use interface for making bootable Ubuntu USB sticks. The full instructions can be found at the [Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick).